# Is there any use for capture groups in a negative lookaround?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

In a regex, it can be useful to capture text in a positive lookahead or lookbehind. However, Oniruguma (for example) supports capture groups in *negative* lookahead (though not in negative lookbehind). As best I can figure, this can *never* result in a value for the capture. Am I correct, or have I missed something?

Comment: What aspect are you interested in? Whether you can access the captured contents or any use case?

Comment: I am wondering, more or less, if anything at all would be lost if capture groups in lookaheads were not implemented. And it seems like the answer is yes — if @PaulCrovella posts his comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture group can be used by a backreference within the lookaround itself. For example:

```
a(?!(.)\1)
```

This will match `a` only if it's not immediately followed by a repeating character. So "ab" would land a match but "abb" would not.

https://regex101.com/r/Iw3Rwt/1